# Getting an error when add i++ react js es6 jsx

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am getting an error when adding additional line to code (`i++`), i would like to know where the code should be added.

```
let i = 1;
this.props.client_name.split(",").map((entry0) => (
    this.props.campaign_name.split(",").map((entry1) => (
        this.props.adset_name.split(",").map((entry2) => (
            ( item.client_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(entry0.toLowerCase()) !== -1  && item.campaign_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(entry1.toLowerCase()) !== -1  && item.adsets_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(entry2.toLowerCase()) !== -1    )?
                **i++**
                (<Task key={item._id} id={item.adsets_id} i={key} item={item} date_from={this.state.date_from} date_to={this.state.date_to} campaign_name={this.state.campaign_name} adset_name={this.state.adset_name} />)
            :
                (null)
        ))

    ))
))
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you have a few asterisks before and after `i++`... Joking aside, please don't use markdown formatting in code snippets, they won't work. If you want to mark out a special line, then use comments instead.

Comment: Oh, and if you get an error, then please *tell* us the error you get. Copy it (as text) and paste it into the question body.

Comment: Don't forget that JavaScript supports useful things like `if`, so you don't have to resort to multiline conditional operators!

Comment: Also, you can probably just use `map(usefulVariableName, index)`, where `index` will give you the index of the current item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using two expression here:

```
condition? i++ (<Task ..../>) : null;
```

Wrap them in `()`, Write it like this:

```
condition? (i++, <Task ..../>) : null;
```

First it will increment the value of i, then return the Task component.

Check [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for more details about ternary operator.

Check this snippet:

```js
var a = 1;
var b = true? (a++, a): 0;

console.log('b', b);
```